# what is %d used for in arrays on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I presume it means `double` but what does it mean in general?

```
 $wpdb->delete(
      "data",
      [ 'id' => $id ],
      [ '%d' ]
    );
```

I get that I'm deleting from table data using array id => id but what is the %d for?

**Why am I asking?**  well, I'd like to do some bulk updates as shown through the features built in with [wp_list_table](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_list_table/) as shown through [this tutorial.](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/)  As I've looked around for that first link I found a few more sources on how to fix my table - I'm just trying do multiple operations and I'm stuck with bulkupdater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its to identify the type of data to be deleted think `where=%d` which means interger

others include:

```
%d - interger (just to make it clear)
%f - float
%s - string
```

so your code

```
$wpdb->delete(
  "data",
  [ 'id' => $id ],
  [ '%d' ]
);
```

Is only going to delete an id where the id string is an integer e.g. 43 not if a43

You can have obviously a few types in an array, but they need to match the order of the data array (i.e. `array('id'=>$id, 'numval'=>$num) ,array(integer, integer)` )